# i want to modify a property value of json using angularjs1 but after modification it replace the whole json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object, updates

i have a dynamic JSON

```
{
"data": {
    "cols": ["3016", "3017", "3018", "3019", "3020", "3021", "3022", "3023"],
    "consumer_desc": " ",
    "form_id": "16",
    "ph_id": "409",
    "seasons": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "usage": [
        ["1", "4", "7"],
        ["2", "5", "8"],
        ["3", "6", "9"]
    ],
    "user_id": "6",
    "vals": [{
        "season": "SUMMER",
        "usage": [
            ["NORMAL", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["PEAK", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["OFF-PEAK", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["TOTAL SUMMER", "=SUM(B1:B3)", "=SUM(C1:C3)", "=SUM(D1:D3)", "=SUM(E1:E3)", "=SUM(F1:F3)", "=SUM(G1:G3)", "=SUM(H1:H3)", "=SUM(I1:I3)"]
        ]
    }, {
        "season": "MONSOON",
        "usage": [
            ["NORMAL", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["PEAK", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["OFF-PEAK", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["TOTAL MONSOON", "=SUM(B1:B3)", "=SUM(C1:C3)", "=SUM(D1:D3)", "=SUM(E1:E3)", "=SUM(F1:F3)", "=SUM(G1:G3)", "=SUM(H1:H3)", "=SUM(I1:I3)"]
        ]
    }, {
        "season": "WINTER",
        "usage": [
            ["NORMAL", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["PEAK", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["OFF-PEAK", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["TOTAL WINTER", "=SUM(B1:B3)", "=SUM(C1:C3)", "=SUM(D1:D3)", "=SUM(E1:E3)", "=SUM(F1:F3)", "=SUM(G1:G3)", "=SUM(H1:H3)", "=SUM(I1:I3)"]
        ]
    }]
},
"message": "Form 1.9(b) matrix fetched Successfully",
"status": 1
}
```

I want to update the `"consumer_desc"` using a scope value. So I have written

```
$scope.subStationsData.consumer_desc = $scope.searchName;
  var  raw = $scope.subStationsData;
  console.log('raw: ',raw);
  console.log('$scope.searchName: ',$scope.searchName);
```

In `$scope.subStationsData` I get the JSON dynamically and in `$scope.searchName` I get the value which i want to add on "consumer_desc". But when I console the raw I get

> raw:  [consumer_desc: "testing"] $scope.searchName:  testing

I want to get

```
{
"data": {
    "cols": ["3016", "3017", "3018", "3019", "3020", "3021", "3022", "3023"],
    "consumer_desc": "testing",
    "form_id": "16",
    "ph_id": "409",
    "seasons": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "usage": [
        ["1", "4", "7"],
        ["2", "5", "8"],
        ["3", "6", "9"]
    ],
    "user_id": "6",
    "vals": [{
        "season": "SUMMER",
        "usage": [
            ["NORMAL", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["PEAK", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["OFF-PEAK", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["TOTAL SUMMER", "=SUM(B1:B3)", "=SUM(C1:C3)", "=SUM(D1:D3)", "=SUM(E1:E3)", "=SUM(F1:F3)", "=SUM(G1:G3)", "=SUM(H1:H3)", "=SUM(I1:I3)"]
        ]
    }, {
        "season": "MONSOON",
        "usage": [
            ["NORMAL", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["PEAK", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["OFF-PEAK", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["TOTAL MONSOON", "=SUM(B1:B3)", "=SUM(C1:C3)", "=SUM(D1:D3)", "=SUM(E1:E3)", "=SUM(F1:F3)", "=SUM(G1:G3)", "=SUM(H1:H3)", "=SUM(I1:I3)"]
        ]
    }, {
        "season": "WINTER",
        "usage": [
            ["NORMAL", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["PEAK", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["OFF-PEAK", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
            ["TOTAL WINTER", "=SUM(B1:B3)", "=SUM(C1:C3)", "=SUM(D1:D3)", "=SUM(E1:E3)", "=SUM(F1:F3)", "=SUM(G1:G3)", "=SUM(H1:H3)", "=SUM(I1:I3)"]
        ]
    }]
},
"message": "Form 1.9(b) matrix fetched Successfully",
"status": 1
}
```

I will be thankful if you please help me to solve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.subStationsData.data.consumer_desc = $scope.searchName;
```

Try this.

Comment: did you assign you dynamic json to subStationsData ?

Comment: yes, dynamic json is assign to subStationData. Before updating the consumer_desc json is shown perfectly in console